# Which Sci-Fi or Fantasy work introduced the idea of TV preternaturally harming people?

Tags: history-of

In *Doctor Who (2005)* episode *The Idiot's Lantern*, Rose and lots of people were sucked by TV to remove their faces.

Interestingly, it wasn't my first encounter with such an idea. Long before new Doctor Who came into existence, I watched this in an Indian horror TV show *Ssshhhh... Koi Hai* on Star Plus (India). In it, a Reality Show used to suck people inside.

Other than this, there's an old Indian remix song [Chod Do Aanchal Zamana Kya Kahega](https://youtu.be/UdtrHwXvbug) featuring the same thing. While this isn't a Sci-Fi or Fantasy work, it can still be used to show that the idea is a widespread thing.

Which Sci-Fi (or Fantasy) work introduced the idea of TV harming people preternaturally (outside of the normal sense of things)?

Comment: I don’t think science-fiction introduced the idea. Every new technology has been accompanied by howls of fear and confusion from the general populace.

Comment: Well, *Poltergeist* goes back to 1982. *A Scientific Fact* was released in 1979.

Comment: Are you talking about any sort of "harm", including TV disturbing our mental faculties? Or are you interested more specifically in the sort of magical-seeming direct physical influences seen in *Doctor Who* and *Aahat*, where TV can reach out and attack you, pull you into itself, etc.? If the latter, *Videodrome* (1983) would be another early example.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ofcourse, I am talking on a SFF site. Sorry for the confusion. Edited the question.

Comment: @SS: naw, your question wasn’t really confusing. And I don’t think there’s anything wrong with asking which sci-fi work first used the idea of people being harmed by TV.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you only want supernaturally inspired self-motivated televisions? That doesn't match with your currently accepted answer.

Comment: @Sean Maybe, I didn't understand your comment, but doesn't the Twonky TV harm people supernaturally (by advanced tech or magic)?

Comment: Ah. This may be a translation issue. "Supernatural" is generally not used to refer to advanced technology in English, but rather to magic and ghosts and such.

Comment: @Sean Then, give me proper word. Previously, it was *Sentiently* which I suppose also was not correct because the TV may not not be sentient. Then, Paul replaced it with *Supernaturally* which according to you is wrong.

Comment: @Sean Yeah, it can be advanced tech or magic. It should just be beyond normal. Also, it doesn't matter TV itself is doing everything or someone behind the curtain doing everything using TV.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to go ahead and delete my later comments so as to avoid cluttering things up.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Ooh preternaturally is way better than supernaturally, good work chaps.

Comment: @Sean Nice word. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 1942 short story ["The Twonky"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46579) by "Lewis Padgett" ([Henry Kuttner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kuttner) and [C. L. Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._L._Moore)), which originally appeared in [*Astounding Science-Fiction*, September 1942](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57666+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v30n01_1942-09_missing_fcifc#page/n31/mode/2up)), was about a sentient **radio-phonograph**; however, in the movie adaptation [*The Twonky*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twonky) (1953), it was changed to a TV:

> After seeing his wife off on her trip, Kerry West, a philosophy teacher at a small-town college, goes inside his home to contemplate his new purchase – a television set. Sitting down in his office, he places a cigarette in his mouth and is about to light it when a beam shoots from the television screen lighting it for him. Absentmindedly unaware of what has taken place, it is only when the television subsequently lights his pipe that West realizes that his television is behaving abnormally.
>
> West soon discovers that the television can walk and perform a variety of functions, including dishwashing, vacuuming, and card-playing. When the television deliveryman returns to settle the bill, the television materializes copies of a five-dollar bill in order to provide payment. Yet the television soon exhibits other, more controlling traits, permitting West only a single cup of coffee and breaking West’s classical music records in favor of military marches to which it dances. After West demonstrates the television to his friend Coach Trout, the coach declares the television set to be a “twonky”, the word he used as a child to label the inexplicable.
>
> Trout soon concludes that the Twonky is a robot committed to serving West. When he tests his hypothesis by attempting to kick West, the Twonky paralyzes his leg. After tending to the coach, West attempts to write a lecture on the role of individualism in art, but the Twonky hits him with beams that alter his thoughts and censors his reading. When West attempts to give his lecture the next day, he finds himself unable to do more than ramble on about trivialities. Frustrated, West goes to the store from which his wife had ordered the television and demands that they take it back or exchange it.
>
> Meanwhile, at West’s house, the coach has summoned members of the college's football team and ordered them to destroy the Twonky. West arrives with the television deliveryman and his replacement set, only to find the players passed out in front of the machine. When West wakes them up, they appear to be in a hypnotic state mumbling that they have “no complaints,” a condition the Twonky soon inflicts on the deliveryman as well. Upstairs, Trout theorizes that the Twonky is from a future “super state” that uses such machines to control the population, which the Twonky soon demonstrates by walking into the room and altering his mind so that he no longer believes there to be a problem. As the now-fixed Trout attempts to leave, police storm into the house in response to a call made by the device seeking female companionship for West, followed by Treasury men tracking down the $5 bills manufactured by the device. When the law enforcement officers attempt to arrest West, though, the Twonky places all of them in a trance, and they leave without complaint.
>
> Frustrated, West escapes the house and returns drunk, only to have the Twonky return him to sobriety with a ray. When his wife returns to see a visiting bill collector driven from their home by the machine, West decides to take action. Luring the device into his car, he attempts to crash it by a variety of means but is frustrated by the Twonky’s ability to control the vehicle. Spotting a vehicle parked alongside the road, West pulls over and abandons his car, hitching a ride from the other driver, an elderly Englishwoman. His relief at having escaped is soon negated by the woman’s erratic driving, and by the discovery that the Twonky was able to hide in the trunk. When the Twonky attempts to stop the woman’s reckless driving, it precipitates a crash that destroys the device for good.

Answer (score 5):

[The Twonky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?189831) (1942) is about a future "TV", sent back to our time, which serves to re-educate the people of its time (basically reprogramming their minds). Bad Things happen to its new owners in our time.

Comment: Does this include harming people?

Comment: Yeah, it'll be counted. :) Thanks for adding the last line.

Comment: It was a fair comment after I thought about it :) I'm just too familiar with the story.

Comment: In the 1942 short story the twonky was a radio, not a TV. It became a TV in the movie.

Answer (score 3):

Ahem...

[*The Monkees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkees), season 2, [episode 26 titled "Mijacogeo"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0650673/) (1968) featured a televised surreal (American) football-headed alien creature called a [Frodis](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Mijacogeo) to hypnotize TV viewers and [Take Over the World](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeOverTheWorld).

Answer (score 0):

Until we get an earlier case, I'm going to suggest *[A Scientific Fact](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51560)* by Joe Haldeman, published in 1979. It's about human memory running out of storage space thanks to TV.

Comment: Updated the question. Here, TV or TV program needs to act as sentient.